# sqlldr shell script import csv to oracle

Tags: shell, sh, sql-loader

ihave a shell script like this, when i run this code in crontab this wont work, please tell me something wrong with my code, this is my shell

```
#!/bin/bash
    NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T')";
    echo "##############################################";
    echo "START : $NOW";

    SQLLDR=`/usr/bin/sqlldr userid=TUNAIREPO/TUNAIREPO#2015@10.250.193.102:1521/optun control=/result/tcash_d/doLoad/ora_new.ctl log=/result/tcash_d/doLoad/ora.log b$
    echo "SQLLDR: $SQLLDR";

    echo "##############################################";
    echo "FINISH : $NOW";
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: in my log this is just show 

START : 2018-06-07 12:54:01
SQLLDR:
##############################################
FINISH : 2018-06-07 12:54:01
SQLLDR:
##############################################
FINISH : 2018-06-07 12:54:01

Comment: the data does not go into the database

Answer (score 0):

The SQLLDR command substitution line should end with a backquote.  Even better use the `$(command)` preferred command substitution syntax.  What's the b$ at the end of that line, a typo?

Also, change that password now that you've shared it with the world!